# Problema al utilizar mysqli::fetch_assoc() en PHP con MySql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli, php7

**Tengo un problema un poco frustrante** al utilizar la función mysqli::fetch_assoc() con PHP. El error que me sale en la linea 21, es el siguiente:

> Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method mysqli::fetch_assoc() in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\GENERAL\Objetos\registro.php:21 Stack trace: #0 {main}
>   thrown in

```
<?php 

if(isset($_POST['boton'])){ //Se ejecuta cuando el boton se haya accionado
    $conexion = new mysqli("localhost","root","","pruebas"); //Conecta con la base de datos de la forma POO
    if($conexion->connect_errno){ //Verifica si existe un error al intenter conectar con la bd
        echo "<p class='mensaje'>* Falló la conexión con la BD  {$conexion->connect_errno}</p><br>";
    }
    $conexion->set_charset("utf8"); //Tolerancia a caracteres latinos

    //Extrae los datos enviados desde el formulario
    $nombre = $conexion->real_escape_string($_POST['nombre']);
    $contrasena = $conexion->real_escape_string($_POST['contrasena']);
    $confirmar_contrasena = $conexion->real_escape_string($_POST['confirmar_contrasena']);
    if($contrasena != $confirmar_contrasena){
        echo "<p class='mensaje'>* Las contraseñas no coinciden</p>";
    }

    //Verifica si el formulario ingresado, ya existe
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM data"; 
    $consulta = $conexion->query($sql);
    while($registro = $conexion->fetch_assoc($consulta)){ //Revisa todos los registros
        if($registro['nombre'] == $nombre){ //Ya existe el mismo registro?
            echo "<p class='mensaje'>* Ya existe un usario con ese nombre</p><br>";
            exit();
        }
    }
    $sql = "INSERT INTO data ('nombre','contraseña') VALUE ({$nombre},{$contrasena})";
    $consulta = $conexion->query($sql);
    if(!$consulta){ //Fallo en la consulta
        echo "<p class='mensaje'>* Falló el registro en la BD</p><br>";
    }
    else{ //Todo está correcto
        echo "<p class='mensaje' style='color : green;'>¡ Te has registrado con exito !</p><br>";
    }
    $conexion->close();
}

?>
```

Comment: y si pruebas con `$registro = $consulta->fetch_assoc()` ? dentro de tu bucle `while`

Comment: De acuerdo a los ejemplos de la documentación de [php](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php) asignas a una variable el procesamiento de la consulta  y luego dentro del bucle obtienes el array asociativo asignado por cada iteración a la variable `$registro`

Comment: ahora si revisamos al inicio de la documentación vemos que solo el estilo procedimental es donde la función recibe un parámetro, similar a lo que tu estas tratando de hacer, sin embargo tu estás trabajando bajo un estilo orientado a objetos por lo cual no debería recibir un parámetro como te planteo en mi primer comentario; de todos modos checa esto https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php

Comment: Muchas gracias, no había tenido eso en cuenta

Comment: Sí, efectivamente ya pude resolver ese pequeño error.

Comment: @WalkRock si la respuesta es correcta márcala como aceptada, por favor, así ayudas al buen funcionamiento de SO.

Comment: Para el `INSERT` usa consultas preparadas, tu código es vulnerable a ataques de *Inyección SQL*. Cuando puedas investiga sobre el tema y sobre cómo puedes evitar ese riesgo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

De acuerdo a la documentación de [PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php)

> El método `mysqli_fetch_assoc()` y `mysqli_fetch_assoc` sirven para obtener una fila de resultado como un array asociativo

solo el estilo procedimental es donde la función recibe un parámetro, similar a lo que tu estas tratando de hacer, sin embargo tu estás trabajando bajo un estilo orientado a objetos por lo cual no debería recibir un parámetro

Entonces tu código debería verse dentro del bucle `while` del modo siguiente

**Estilo orientado a objetos**

```
while($registro = $consulta->fetch_assoc()){
  ........
}
```

**Estilo procedimental**

```
while ($registro = mysqli_fetch_assoc($consulta)) {
     ............
}
```